# Delegate Command executes on base class not derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates, command

I wonder if anyone can shed some light on an issue I just had to resolve.

I have a base window which has a delegate command which fires a method designed to make visible a specific view within the main window

The assumption is that there is a possibility data could be corrupt and a given view may not be usable so I have a user control which displays an error message and has a button that fires this command to switch to a more low level view where the data can be corrected.

I then inherit the base window and in my derived window I have a tab control, each with different views. I override the switch method to switch to a tab item that contains my low level view.

Then on the other tabs I implement the user control with the button.

The problem I am facing is that on the first tab the button works fine, however on each subsequent tab the execute method always calls the base class method, not the derived class method.

I change the order of tabs it is always the first tab that works correctly and subsequent tabs that fail to call the derived method.

I can resolve the problem by changing the command to a RoutedCommand and then execute always calls the derived method.

But I am confused as to why the delegate command does not work and why am I seeing the above behaviour?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

---

Yeah I suppose code might be useful :) I have added some snippets of code that might help show my intentions.

Please note I have tried many different variations of this code, including using a non-static delegate command and using a custom delegate command (not from prism) but only the use of a routed command seems to work

base window:

```
    public static DelegateCommand<object> SwitchToXmlOnError;

    public WindowBase()
    {

        SwitchToXmlOnError = new DelegateCommand<object>(SwitchToXml, CanSwitch);
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding(SwitchToXmlOnError));
    }

protected bool CanSwitch(object e)
{
    return true;
}

protected void SwitchToXml(object e)
{
    this.SwitchToXmlErrorExecute(e);
}

protected virtual void SwitchToXmlErrorExecute(object sender)
{
    //To be implemented by derived class
}
```

derived window:

```
protected override void SwitchToXmlErrorExecute(object sender)
{
    //some code to change selected tab item
}
```

button in user control:

```
<Button x:Name="lnkOpenXmlDocument" BorderThickness="0" Content="Switch To Xml" Command="inf:WindowBase.SwitchToXmlOnError" CommandParameter="{Binding XmlValidationException}" />
```

user control implemented in other views:

```
                    <appCtrl:XmlErrorCtrl >
                        <appCtrl:XmlErrorCtrl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type appCtrl:XmlErrorCtrl}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsXmlValid}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsXmlValid}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </appCtrl:XmlErrorCtrl.Style>
                    </appCtrl:XmlErrorCtrl>
```

The tab control on my main window: (custom tab control is merely an inherited tab control with SelectedItemChanging event

```
<Grid>
    <ctrl:CustomTabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" SelectionChanging="MainTabControl_SelectionChanging_1" >
        <ctrl:CustomTabItem x:Name="GeneralTabItem" Header="{Binding GeneralTabVM.Title}" >
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <view:GeneralTabEnhancedView x:Name="generalDetailsView" MinHeight="650" MinWidth="700" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ctrl:CustomTabItem>
        <ctrl:CustomTabItem x:Name="SetingsTabItem" Header="{Binding SettingTabVM.Title}" >
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <view:SettingsView x:Name="settingsView" MinHeight="400"  />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ctrl:CustomTabItem>
        <ctrl:CustomTabItem x:Name="XmlTabItem"  DataContext="{Binding XMLEditorTabVM}" Header="{Binding Title}" >
            <editor:SyntaxEditor x:Name="MainXmlEditor"
                                 IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=DataQueryView, Path=IsReadOnly}" 
                                 Foreground="Black" SyntaxHighlighting="XML" Document="{Binding XmlDocument}"
                                 Loaded="MainXmlEditor_Loaded_1" Unloaded="MainXmlEditor_Unloaded_1"/>
        </ctrl:CustomTabItem>
    </ctrl:CustomTabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It would be *really* useful if you could just give a short but complete code example demonstrating the problem - much easier to follow than just a description which may well not include some vital aspect.

Comment: post your code and xaml.

Comment: ok have posted some snippets, sorry but I thought just an explanation might be enough.

Comment: ok, thanks for asking me to post code, it has prompted me to try and create a sample project... though it appears its not directly the command at fault as I can get the above to work correctly in a new project so I will have to investigate further into what is affecting my main project